# R create conditional incrementing categorical variable over time per group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of data over time and split by group. There is a binary field that related to a users' status. A user can remain in this status for a period of time, or exit. I wish to create a counter that is specific to each user that increments every time a user enters and reenters a status period. Each time point between the start of a status period retains the same value.

Desired output `Status_Count`:

```
Date        User_ID   Status  Status_Count
01/01/2022     1        0        0
01/02/2022     1        0        0
01/03/2022     1        1        1
01/04/2022     1        1        1
01/05/2022     1        1        1
01/06/2022     1        0        0
01/07/2022     1        0        0
01/08/2022     1        1        2
01/09/2022     1        1        2
01/10/2022     1        0        0
01/11/2022     1        0        0
01/12/2022     1        0        0
01/01/2022     2        0        0
01/02/2022     2        1        1
01/03/2022     2        1        1
01/04/2022     2        1        1
01/05/2022     2        0        0
01/06/2022     2        0        0
01/07/2022     2        1        2
01/08/2022     2        1        2
01/09/2022     2        0        0
01/10/2022     2        0        0
01/11/2022     2        1        3
01/12/2022     2        0        0
```

Example data:

```
Date <- rep(seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-12-01'), by = "month"), 2)
User_ID <- c(rep.int(1, 12), rep.int(2, 12))
Status<- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Status_Counter <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0)
Example_Data <- data.frame(Date, User_ID, Status, Status_Counter)
```

My attempt at coding this:

```
library(dplyr)

Example_Data <- Example_Data %>%
  group_by(User_ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Counter = case_when(
      Event == 1 & (Status != lag(Status, 1) | is.na(lag(Status, 1))) ~ cumsum(Status),
      Event == 1 ~ cumsum(Status),
      TRUE ~ 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Example_Data %>%
  mutate(counter = Status*cumsum(Status > lag(Status, default = 0)), .by = User_ID)
```

Result

```
         Date User_ID Status Status_Counter counter
1  2022-01-01       1      0              0       0
2  2022-02-01       1      0              0       0
3  2022-03-01       1      1              1       1
4  2022-04-01       1      1              1       1
5  2022-05-01       1      1              1       1
6  2022-06-01       1      0              0       0
7  2022-07-01       1      0              0       0
8  2022-08-01       1      1              2       2
9  2022-09-01       1      1              2       2
10 2022-10-01       1      0              0       0
11 2022-11-01       1      0              0       0
12 2022-12-01       1      0              0       0
13 2022-01-01       2      0              0       0
14 2022-02-01       2      1              1       1
15 2022-03-01       2      1              1       1
16 2022-04-01       2      1              1       1
17 2022-05-01       2      0              0       0
18 2022-06-01       2      0              0       0
19 2022-07-01       2      1              2       2
20 2022-08-01       2      1              2       2
21 2022-09-01       2      0              0       0
22 2022-10-01       2      0              0       0
23 2022-11-01       2      1              3       3
24 2022-12-01       2      0              0       0
```